# Set Max-width for Tags in Bootstrap Tags Input

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-tags-input

The Tags in `Bootstrap Tags Input` is overflowing the container.

So I would like to set max-width for the Tag or is there any way to stop overflowing the Tags in `Bootstrap Tags Input` ?

For Reference please visit [this web site](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

Comment: Post a screenshot of the issue so we can help more easily.

Comment: Yes, But i don't have enough Resputations to post screenshot.

Comment: A small, reproducible example would help, maybe in a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) or [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). Or at least include the _relevant_ CSS/HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add An Bootstrap-Tagsinput Event:

```
$('#Id').on('itemAdded', function(obj) {

    var tagsinputWidth = $('#Id').parent().find('.bootstrap-tagsinput').width();// Width of Bootstrap Tags Input.
    var tagWidth = $('#Id').parent().find('.bootstrap-tagsinput span.tag').last().width();// To get the Width of individual Tag.
    if(tagWidth > tagsinputWidth) {
        //If Width of the Tag is more than the width of Container then we crop text of the Tag
        var tagsText = obj.item.value;// To Get Tags Value
        var res = tagsText.substr(0, 5); // Here I'm displaying only first 5 Characters.(You can give any number)  
        $('#Id').parent().find('.bootstrap-tagsinput span.tag').last().html(res+"..." +'<span data-role="remove"></span>');
    }
});
```

But the Problem is, User can't see the total text of tag that he/she added. So we can place "Title" for the Tag

We need to customize in bootstrap-tagsinput.js at line Number 127.

```
var $tag = $('<span class="tag ' + htmlEncode(tagClass) + '" title="'+htmlEncode(itemText)+'">' + htmlEncode(itemText) + '<span data-role="remove"></span></span>');
```

So, Now the User Can visible the Text when he/she mouse-over on that particular Tag.

Comment: Fine Onteru..! , It works Fine. But i hope this is handy solution. Still i'm waiting for Optimal Solution. Any way now i'm going with your solution. Thank you soo much. Keep it up.